# Calculate difference between paged rows in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a entity containing a Date and some numeric value, like this:

```
public sealed class ResultEntry : Entity
{
    public DateTime ReportedUtc { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Calculating the difference over time would be quite easy. Order the entries by date and calculate the difference

```
(entry.Value - previousEntry.Value) / previousEntry.Value
```

But what would be the best approach if the result is returned in a paged approach like this:

```
var entries = dbContext.Skip((paged.Index - 1) * paged.Size).Take(paged.Size)
```

If there are 10 entries, you take 5 entries per query and you are on page 2. The first retrieved entry won't have any previous entry to calculate a difference against.

Comment: You need to test if index is 0 before subtracting one.

Comment: Better to write SQL and execute via Dapper. You have to use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) Window Function.